# Finding a formule for the derivative $\exp(f(x)),\, x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: derivatives, calculus

Suposse that $f\in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
How find a formule for
$$\partial_{x}^{\alpha} \mathrm{e}^{f(x)}$$ for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_{0}^n$ multiindex?

Comment: What's wrong with the Leibniz rule?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Chain rule for partial derivatives.  Find it in your calculus textbook.